# django test client always returning 301

Tags: django, django-testing, mezzanine, cartridge

I've run into some problems while running cartridge tests - the test client always returns 301 when doing something like self.client.get('/'). The only way to proceed is adding follow=True, but it's suspicious that I always have to do that. This also means I cannot test POST, since the [test client always uses GET for redirects](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12607).

I've modified cartridge in a few places, so this is definitely my fault, but I'm not sure how to debug it. Here's what happens:

```
>>> response = self.client.get('/en/')
>>> response.status_code
301
>>> pp response.__dict__
{'_base_content_is_iter': False,
 '_charset': 'utf-8',
 '_closable_objects': [],
 '_container': [u''],
 '_handler_class': None,
 '_headers': {'content-language': ('Content-Language', 'en'),
              'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
              'location': ('Location', 'http://example.com/en/'),
              'vary': ('Vary', 'Accept-Language, Cookie')},
 'client': <django.test.client.Client object at 0x1105364d0>,
 'context': None,
 'cookies': <SimpleCookie: >,
 'request': {u'CONTENT_TYPE': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
             u'PATH_INFO': '/en/',
             u'QUERY_STRING': '',
             u'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET'},
 'templates': []}
```

And with following redirects:

```
>>> response = self.client.get('/en/', follow=True)
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response.redirect_chain
[('http://example.com/en/', 301)]

>>> response = self.client.get('http://example.com/en/')
>>> response.status_code
301
>>> response['Location']
'http://example.com/en/'
```

Even when I try to go directly to the given URL:

```
>>> response = self.client.get('http://example.com/en/', follow=True)
>>> response.redirect_chain
[('http://example.com/en/', 301)]
```

where 'example.com' is just the sites live url. Do you have any ideas why that might be happening? Is it normal that it redirects to example.com (or at least pretends, it still seems to be running locally) instead of localhost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standardly I've figured out the answer while writing the question... hopefully this will be useful to somebody else!

Somehow the SSL config snuck into my dev settings. In particular I've had the following

```
SSL_FORCE_HOST = 'example.com'
```

enabled, which seems to be a problem - after disabling it in dev, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I was inexplicably getting a 301 PermanentRedirect when testing my django views, and had run out of ideas. Your question and answer made me realize that the SSL settings were producing a redirect.

Comment: Me too, I had an ssl middleware setting that caused the 301 status code. Would've probably cost me a lot of time without your clue. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me using django-sslify. Needed `from django.test.utils import override_settings` and to use the decorator `@override_settings(SSLIFY_DISABLE=True)` on my `TestCase` class. Works for Django 1.4+

Comment: My unit tests were failing for this exact reason. I just switched off sslify when testing. 

`if bool(int(os.getenv("IN_PRODUCTION", 1))) == 1: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = tuple(['sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware'] + list(MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES))`

Comment: It wasn't SSL for me but this made me realize I was running my tests using the deploy config file, not the development.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a `secure` flag that you can set to solve the issue with redirection to https. In my case I tested `post`:

```
response = self.client.post(url, data, secure=True)
```

but `client.get()` also has this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Check that it is running the test with debug enabled in `settings.py`. Running with debug disabled can causes it to redirect.

```
DEBUG = True
```

I encountered this in a code base that was modified to disable debug by default.